# AspNetCore OData not working on .NET Core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-3.0

I just upgraded an ASP.NET Core 2.2 project to ASP.NET Core 3.0 and my OData endpoints refuse to work. During startup, I get the following error:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionConstraintCache' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.'

How does one work around this type resolution issue?

Comment: Yeah basically they made ActionConstraintCache internal in .net core 3. So if you want odata to work right now, just manually fix it  in the odata assembly or wait until odata is supported by .net core 3

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a clear timeline around this though. I did see in one of the reported issues a tirade about Microsoft not giving as much love to OData as they are doing with gRPC.

Comment: You just have to put in some hacks to get it working.  see this [thread](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1748#issuecomment-537551659)

Comment: @johnny5, thanks. I reviewed the thread and others like it. It seems we have to wait and see if something will be ready by the time .NET Core 3.1 goes RTM.

I don't have the bandwidth to come up with the workarounds. Mine is a small team and we have a ton of deliverables.

Answer (score 12):

I've been trying to fight this error all day. Finally found out the problem: Odata is simply not compatible yet with .NET Core 3.0. Follow [this thread](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1748) for a bit more information.

Comment: So, is there any word on when this library will be progressed to .NET Core 3?

Comment: I do not know how they (and in general MS) do not recognize, that OData Team is practically blocking the migration or upgrade to .NET Core 3? OData team is whining about the "hard" changes in .NET Core since literally 10 months. Sorry to hear that developers life so hard. A even few month ago they defended themself as ".NET Core is still in preview 5, there is plenty of time to be ready when the release comes in." They blocked the migration/update during the pre-release phase,  and now after the release still blocking, still excuses. Sorry for your wasted time, I did the same 3 month ago.

Comment: @g.pickardou, let's hope they see it and act on it. The discontent around this seems to be growing in the community.

Comment: Any news on this :)

Comment: @DživoJelić The Odata team and the ASP.NET Team are now working on it and are expecting an early version on the end of the month:
https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1748#issuecomment-553293774

Meanwhile, if you really need it, you could check out this:
https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1748#issuecomment-554484326 
I havn't tried it out tho.

Comment: Nightly with .net core 3 support has been released: https://www.myget.org/feed/webapinetcore/package/nuget/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData